# Feign get stuck inside Asnyc Method In Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, future, openfeign

I am using feing client inside a async method and this method returns Future.
But while i am running service, feign get stuck and I never see response log from feign client. Code block get stuck there and service stop to available . Code blocks below:

```
    
@Async
    public Future<ReportResponse> getId(String id) {
        ReportResponse response = client.getReport(id);
        log.info("resp for " + response);
        return new AsyncResult<>(ReportResponse);
    }
```

```
 List<Future<ReportResponse>> futuresList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String id : Ids) {
            futuresList.add(reportService.getId(id));
        }

        for (Future<ReportResponse> future :
                futuresList) {
            try {
                ReportResponse reponse = future.get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
```

```
@FeignClient(name = "service", url = "${url}", configuration = FeignClientProperties.FeignClientConfiguration.class)
public interface Client {

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}"
    ReportResponse getId(@PathVariable String id);
}
```

Dependency i used:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks.

Comment: you can/should set a timeout like `future.get(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` ...but of course you should also "find & eliminate/avoid the root cause";)

Comment: javadoc: "Throws:
CancellationException - if the computation was cancelled;
ExecutionException - if the computation threw an exception;
InterruptedException - if the current thread was interrupted while waiting;
TimeoutException - if the wait timed out"

Comment: Unfortunately There is no exception thrown, just stuck " ReportResponse response = client.getReport(id);" and does not print "resp for". Also I set timeout as you suggest but same result.

Comment: ..but it has to stuck  `#futureList.size()` times! ;)

Comment: ..and then after 10 seconds(as i proposed) throw (n times) a `TimeoutException` ...

Comment: what is that `client`!?

Comment: I dont want throws exception, I want feign receive response and return response as Future.

Comment: Is the service available? Have you tried to call it manually? It's useful to understand where the call is get stuck. If the service is up and running, then switch on your connection pool (if you use one), etc... Try to add the stack trace with the error, maybe it could say something more...

Comment: Service is not available too.